# Windows Workflow 4 with custom instance store not working

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I created a simple workflow service with custom instance store(to support oracle).
The custom instance store, i follow the demo from MSDN: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee829481.aspx][1]
But when i invoke the service api, raise the exception:

> A value of the wrong type was retrieved from the instance store.  A
>   value of type {/Default Web Site/}OrderService.svc was expected, but
>   null was encountered instead.

I try to use SqlWorkflowInstanceStore, it's OK. No problem for service.
I use custom instance store again and debug, i found **LoadWorkflowCommand** be executed before **SaveWorkflowCommand**. I think it's an issue. Need your help!

The following is my code snippet:

```
1. Web Config:
<extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="databaseWorkflowInstanceStore" type="Practices.Framework.Workflow.Configuration.DatabaseInstanceStoreElement, Practices.Framework" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!--<sqlWorkflowInstanceStore connectionStringName="practicesDatabase" instanceCompletionAction="DeleteAll" instanceEncodingOption="GZip" />-->
          <databaseWorkflowInstanceStore database="practicesDatabase" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

2. DatabaseInstanceStore 
    public class DatabaseInstanceStore : InstanceStore
    {
    protected override IAsyncResult BeginTryCommand(InstancePersistenceContext context, InstancePersistenceCommand command, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
            {
                if (command is CreateWorkflowOwnerCommand)
                {
                    var instanceOwnerId = Guid.NewGuid();
                    context.BindInstanceOwner(instanceOwnerId, instanceOwnerId);
                }
                else if (command is LoadWorkflowCommand)
                {
                    var instanceData = this.LoadInstanceData();
                    context.LoadedInstance(InstanceState.Initialized, instanceData, null, null, null);
                }
                else if (command is SaveWorkflowCommand)
                {
                    var saveCommand = (SaveWorkflowCommand)command;
                    var instanceData = saveCommand.InstanceData;

                    this.SaveInstanceData(instanceData);
                }

                return new CompletedAsyncResult<bool>(true, callback, state);
            }

    ......
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN article only shows the bare minimum of commands you need to implement. It sounds like you need to support more command so I would check which commands are dispatched that you don't support yet. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.durableinstancing.instancepersistencecommand.aspx) for a list of commands.

Answer (score 0):

The BeginTryCommand is called with the following commands executed in this order：
1. CreateWorkflowOwnerCommand
2. LoadWorkflowCommand
3. SaveWorkflowCommand
4. SaveWorkflowCommand

So for LoadWorkflowCommand:
I need Create Instance before Load

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/dublin/thread/e51d7b18-1e27-4335-8ad0-4ce76b9f8b91

Comment: How did you create the instance?